# radius in a static google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Does anyone knows how to draw a radius in a static google maps using an url like this?

```
 http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400....
```

I'm looking in the internet but I dont find any example.

best regards.

Comment: There is no such option for static maps. But with a little bit of CSS it should be possible to draw the circle on your own.

Comment: so, do you know how can be achieved using CSS?

Comment: simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/w7jCS/

Comment: ok, I can center the position because I have the coordinates, but the radius would not be ok because in this example you are using percents and I need to add the radius as meters .

Comment: so calculate what you need and set the value to what you want to, it's on you. BTW: the size of the circle is not defined by the border-radius, it's defined by the width/height of the inner div.